# How can I create declarative relationship to multiple tables in SQLAlchemy (polimorphic)

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

How can I create declarative relationship to multiple tables in SQLAlchemy (polimorphic)?

I have Journal object that reflects journal table in database. It holds type and id (as foreign key) in relevant table. What i need, to create declarative class to map this tables.

The structure of database i can't change and can't create additional association table. But i know identifier for objects.

What i'm trying to get you can see at the bottom of the code example.

```
engine = create_engine('sqlite://', echo=True)
metadata = MetaData(bind=engine)
Base = declarative_base(bind=metadata)
DBSession = sessionmaker(bind=engine, autocommit=False, expire_on_commit=False)
session = DBSession()


class Person(Base):
    __abstract__ = True


class Manager(Person):
    __tablename__ = 'managers'

    identifier = '01'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(50))
    manager_data = Column(String(40))

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': identifier,
    }


class Engineer(Person):
    __tablename__ = 'engineers'

    identifier = '02'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(50))
    engineer_info = Column(String(40))

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': identifier,
    }


class Journal(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'journal'

    identifier = '03'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    date = Column(Date)

    type = Column(String(50))
    person_id = Column(Integer)
    person = relationship()     # can’t figure out this relationship

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_on': type,
        'with_polymorphic': '*'
    }


if __name__ == '__main__':

    metadata.create_all()

    en1 = Engineer(id=1)
    mn1 = Manager(id=2)

    session.add_all([en1, mn1])
    session.commit()

    j1 = Journal(person=en1)
    # -> INSERT INTO Journal (type, person_id) VALUES (’02’, 1)

    j2 = Journal(person=mn1)
    # -> INSERT INTO Journal (type, person_id) VALUES (‘01’, 2)

    for row in session.query(Journal):
            print(row, row.person)
    # -> [<Journal …>, <Manager …>]
    # -> [<Journal …>, <Engineer …>]

    for row in session.query(Journal).filter(Journal.type == Manager.identifier):
            print(row, row.person)
    # -> [<Journal …>, <Manager …>]
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Mike Bayer's [article](http://techspot.zzzeek.org/2007/05/29/polymorphic-associations-with-sqlalchemy/) found solution.

```
Base = declarative_base()

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    identifier = '01'

    id = Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column('name', String(50), nullable=False)

class Order(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'orders'
    identifier = '02'

    id = Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True)
    description = Column('description', String(50), nullable=False)


class Address(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'addresses'

    id = Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True)
    addressable_id = Column('addressable_id', Integer)
    addressable_type = Column('addressable_type', String(50))
    street = Column('street', String(100))
    city = Column('city', String(50))
    country = Column('country', String(50))

    def __init__(self, type):
        self.addressable_type = type

    member = property(lambda self: getattr(self, '_backref_%s' % self.addressable_type))


def addressable(cls, name, uselist=True):
    """addressable 'interface'."""

    def create_address(self):
        a = Address(cls.identifier)
        if uselist:
            getattr(self, name).append(a)
        else:
            setattr(self, name, a)
        return a

    cls.create_address = create_address

    mapper = class_mapper(cls)
    table = mapper.local_table

    # no constraints.  therefore define constraints in an ad-hoc fashion.
    primaryjoin = and_(
        list(table.primary_key)[0] == Address.addressable_id,
        Address.addressable_type == cls.identifier
    )

    foreign_keys = [Address.addressable_id]

    mapper.add_property(name, relation(
        Address,
        primaryjoin=primaryjoin, uselist=uselist, foreign_keys=foreign_keys,
        backref=backref(
            '_backref_%s' % cls.identifier,
            primaryjoin=list(table.primary_key)[0] == Address.addressable_id,
            foreign_keys=foreign_keys,
            # lazy="joined"   # Joined strategy
        )
    )
                        )


addressable(User, 'addresses', uselist=True)
addressable(Order, 'address', uselist=False)

e = create_engine("sqlite://", echo=True)
Base.metadata.create_all(e)

u1 = User()
u1.name = 'bob'

o1 = Order()
o1.description = 'order 1'

a1 = u1.create_address()
a1.street = '123 anywhere street'
a2 = u1.create_address()
a2.street = '345 orchard ave'

a3 = o1.create_address()
a3.street = '444 park ave.'

sess = create_session(bind=e)
sess.add(u1)
sess.add(o1)
sess.flush()

# query addresses and get relative objects

for address in sess.query(Address):
    print("Street", address.street, "Member", address.member)
```